# Filter nested div's with jquery

Tags: jquery

This is the html structure I have:

```
<div class="day">
    <div class="date">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="event-container">
        <div class="event">...</div>
        <div class="event">...</div>
        ...
        <div class="event">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to filter this structure by contents of `.event`. If any of the words in search query are not present in `.event` element, it must be hidden. If all `.event`s in an `.event-container` are hidden, whole `.day` must be hidden.

Here is my attempt:

```
var terms = query.split(" ");

$('.day').each(function() {           //iterate over days
    var matches = false;              //does the day contain a valid event?

    $(this).find('.event').each(function() {   //iterate over events of this day
        var evMatches = true;         //does this event contain all terms?

        $.each(terms, function (index, term) {  //iterate over terms
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(term, "i")) < 0)
                evMatches = false;    //if any term isn't found, element is invalid
        });

        if (evMatches)   //if event contained query
        {
            matches = true;  //day contains valid event
            $(this).show();
        }
        else
            $(this).hide();

    });

    if (matches)  //if day contains valid event
        $(this).show();
    else
        $(this).hide();
});
```

I am getting "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

I believe I am doing something wrong in `$.each(terms, ...)` or `$(this).find('event-entry').each(...)` because I don't understand those statements well enough, just trying to put this together from examples and jquery docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` isn't what you think it is inside the loop of `terms`. It has a new context from the `each` that iterates elements

You can't use `this` within an each loop that iterates an array of strings.

When you have nested loops store any `this` references so you know which `this` you are dealing with.

Also try to store values that don't change so you don't have to look the same thing up many many times

```
$('.day').each(function() {          
    var matches = false;             

   var $day = $(this); // store `$(this)` reference

    $day.find('.event').each(function() {   
        var evMatches = true;         

        var $event = $(this), eventText = $event.text();

        $.each(terms, function (index, term) {  
             // use stored text value instead of looking it up each time
            if (eventText.search(new RegExp(term, "i")) < 0)
                evMatches = false;    
        });

        if (evMatches)   //if event contained query
        {
            matches = true;  //day contains valid event
            $event.show();
        }
        else
            $event.hide();

    });

    if (matches)  //if day contains valid event
        $day.show();
    else
       $day.hide();
});
```

Comment: Ah, `this` inside my `$.each` was the same as term, right? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any convention or reason why you store `$(this)` in variables starting with `$` like `$day`.

Comment: no...it's not even the same as `term`. The `$` prefix is a commonly used convention that lets you know it is a jQuery object